# GIT : Run dos2unix commands only on modified files using git status command

Tags: java, git

I changed some java files in my project using FileWriter but after that i face issue like all the file indentation have changed so need to run dos2unix command for each file.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved after run the below command.

Below command print all the files which was modified and remove unwanted text and run dos2unix for each file.

git status | grep modified | sed 's/modified://g' | xargs dos2unix